Docker - Connect image port with server port
I have a python application containerized in docker. I want to host it on my windows server(2019) and access it from everywhere
I have read that in order to access Docker's port as localhost, "port forwarding" must be performed. In other words, i need to connect the port of the host machine and the port of the Docker container.
So im running docker as follows:
$ docker container run -d -p 80:5000 [image_name] where 80 is the port of my server and 5000 is the exposed port of my docker image.
Results:
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Running on http://192.158.233.12:5000
2024-05-10 09:43:06 Press CTRL+C to quit
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Restarting with stat
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debugger is active!
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debugger PIN: 112-336-525
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Serving Flask app 'app'
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debug mode: on


However when trying to access http://192.158.233.12:5000 on browser i get This site cant be reached
Im not sure if this is the correct way of doing what i described but any help would appreciated
DOCKERFILE
# FROM selects the image to find on docker hub and selects the tag specified. 
FROM python:3.8
# this is the work directory
WORKDIR /user/src/app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
# Copy the requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /user/src/app/requirements.txt
# Run the pip - install
#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pyyaml==5.1 install torch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1 torchaudio==0.13.1
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir numpy matplotlib scikit-learn scikit-image opencv-python opencv-contrib-python pandas
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
#RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
# Expose the port that the container will communicate
EXPOSE 4000
# Copy source code and everything
COPY . /user/src/app
CMD [ "python", "app.py"]


Once you've run the docker run -p command, you need to use the host machine's DNS name or IP address, or localhost if you're running the browser on the same system as the container.  The container-private IP addresses are generally unreachable, and the container has no way to find out the host's address.

can you provide an example?

With that docker run command, you should be able to access http://localhost from the same system, targeting the published default HTTP port 80.

Please see [mcve].
